# Searching paths for ViewComponent in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

In general if we use View("Index"). It will search for views in Views/ControllerName or Views/Shared folder. Likewise if we use Component.InvokeAsync("SomeData") then what are the paths it will search for that viewcomponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a component, runtimes will search into components folder as stated below:

- /Views/{Controller Name}/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
- /Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
- /Pages/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}

source: [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 1):

Even though this path is part of the documentation on View Components, by default the following path does not work in .NET 7, Oct 2023.

```
/Pages/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
```

The IDE recognizes this location and if you specify the name of the view, it will be resolved, but the code will not use this path.

I fixed this by adding the following code to the program.cs file.

```
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddRazorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Pages/Shared/{0}.cshtml");
    });
```